# Getting stuck in getIntLimited function

Tags: c

i have a problem in getting stuck in getIntLimited function. In adjustQuantity i need it to check if user entered the right number, not more or less than needed and not letters. I didn't do that to "Stock" option, only in "Check" option. But my first problem is that i have to type the number twice to get a response from it  and the second is that i can't get out of the getIntLimited loop.
Here's the image of the output:
[image]

and the part of my code:

```
void GroceryInventorySystem(void){
    struct Item Items[MAX_ITEM_NO];
    int opt, records;
    int loop = 0;
    welcome();
    while(!loop){
        if(opt == 3){
            adjustQuantity(Items, records, CHECKOUT);
            saveItems(Items, DATAFILE, records);
            if(0 == saveItems(Items, DATAFILE, records)){
                printf("Could not update data file %s\n", DATAFILE);
            }
            pause();
        }
}
int getInt(void){ // Check if user entered the character and breaks, returns the value if a number // 
    char letter = 'x';
    int value;
    while(1){
        scanf("%d%c", &value, &letter);
        if(letter != '\n'){
            printf("Invalid integer, please try again: ");   
            flushKeyboard();
        }else{
            return value;
        }
    }
}

int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit){ // Check if user typed the value higher/lower and repeats. Returns the value if user entered the right number //
    int Value;
    while(1){
        Value = getInt();
        if(Value <= lowerLimit || Value >= upperLimit){
            printf("Invalid value, %d < value < %d: ", lowerLimit, upperLimit); 
        }else{
            return Value;
        }
    }
}
void adjustQuantity(struct Item item[], int NoOfRecs, int stock) {
    int check, sku, index, opt;
    char tostock[] = "to stock", tocheck[] = "to checkout";
    printf("Please enter the SKU: ");
    scanf("%d", &sku);
    check = locateItem(item, NoOfRecs, sku, &index);
    if (check == 0) {
        printf("Item not found!\n");
    } else {
        displayItem(item[index], FORM);
        if (stock == STOCK) {
            printf("Please enter the quantity %s; Maximum of %d or 0 to abort: ", tostock, MAX_QTY - item[index].quantity);
            scanf("%d", &opt);
            if (opt == 0) {
                printf("--== Aborted! ==--\n");
            } else {
                item[index].quantity += opt;
                printf("--== Stocked! ==--\n");
            }
        } else {
            printf("Please enter the quantity %s; Maximum of %d or 0 to abort: ", tocheck, item[index].quantity);
            scanf("%d", &opt);
            if (opt == 0) {
                printf("--== Aborted! ==--\n");
            } else if (item[index].quantity < opt){
                opt = getIntLimited(item[index].quantity, 0);
            } else {
                item[index].quantity -= opt;
                printf("--== Checked out! ==--\n");
                if (item[index].quantity <= opt) {
                    printf("Quantity is low, please reorder ASAP!!!\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually debugged this?

Comment: i did a mistake in opt = getIntLimited(0, item[index].quantity); it should be the opposite like this  opt = getIntLimited(item[index].quantity, 0); now it exits out of the loop whenever i type the right number in between 0 and 5

 . Moving the char letter = 'x'; before scanf("%d%c", &value, &letter); didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

i did a mistake in `opt = getIntLimited(0, item[index].quantity);` it should be the opposite like this `opt = getIntLimited(item[index].quantity, 0);` now it exits out of the loop whenever i type the right number in between 0 and 5 .
I also putted `opt = getIntLimited(0, item[index].quantity);` instead of `scanf`, and removed else if statements